# "à la table" or "à table" for "at the table"

Tags: expressions, articles

> Il y a trois personnes à la table.
>
> Il y a trois personnes à table.

Which one is correct? If both are correct, is there a difference in meaning?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both are correct. In the case of *à la table*, the definite article *la* suggests a certain table, that you can see, or that was talked about previously. In the case of *à table*, the meaning is rather that people are eating, without necessarily saying something about where they sit (they could be sitting at the same table, *or at different tables*, but they are certainly *eating*). In that case, *à table* just means *eating*.

*à table* is also present as a fixed expression in e.g. *à table!* (lunch is ready!) or *passer à table*, which means, literally *go sit at the table for eating*, but that everyone understands simply as *starting dinner, lunch* (forgetting any notion of *table*).

*Table* is easily related to *eating* in French: *une bonne table* means *a good restaurant* for example. Pour plus de détails sur les divers usages de *table* en français, on peut consulter cette (longue) référence: [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/table).

Comment: "à table !" is the idiomatic expression for "lunch is ready !".

Comment: That's more than a generic table, people might well be sitting at **different** tables in the second case.

Comment: J'ai modifié ma réponse pour inclure ces deux précisions. Merci!