# Why "à table" and not "à la table", yet "au lit"

Tags: à, au

The closest to my question is ["à la table" or "à table" for "at the table"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24821/%c3%a0-la-table-or-%c3%a0-table-for-at-the-table)

However, the answer there specifically distinguishes table in a specific and metaphorical sense. But then, I understand au lit to be metaphorical, in the same sense as à table. So why does table have a special usage scenario, without the article?

Comment: They aren't connected: mise à l'eau, mise à mort, and many others I can't think of now. mettre au rencart,

Comment: https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/table → A B b β − ***À table. Pendant le repas***. Il n'y a de véritable réconciliation que celle qui se fait à table (...). « *On passe **à table** pour manger, ensuite on va discuter **à la table** des négociations.* »
♦ *Verbe + à table* : 
[Passer | prendre place | se mettre | venir] à table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Au lit*** indeed matches ***à table***, i.e. is the generic expression, e.g.:

> ***Mes enfants sont au lit*** (The statement doesn't imply are in the same bed.)

If you need something equivalent to ***à** la table*, you say ***dans** le lit*, e.g.:

> ***Il y a deux chats couchés dans le lit.***

The usable prepositions and whether an explicit article or article zero is used depends on the object and is hard to guess.

| Generic | Specific |
| --- | --- |
| *En voiture* | *Dans une voiture* |
| *En ville* | *Dans une ville* |
| *Au lit* | *Dans un lit* |
| *Au restaurant* | *Dans un restaurant* |
| *Au cinéma* | *Dans un cinéma* |
| *À table* | *À une table* |
| *À cheval* | *Sur un cheval* |
| *Au travail* | *À son travail* |

Sometimes, there is no consensus:

*En retraite* vs *À la retraite*

Comment: Is there any background on why à table and au lit match, yet only the latter uses the article? How did that evolve differently?

Comment: The former also uses an article, but it happens to be the "[article zero](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/article_z%C3%A9ro)". See also https://www.persee.fr/doc/linx_0246-8743_1995_hos_6_1_1340